# how to escape '$' in maven pom property value

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I want the maven property value is a raw string `${var}`, not the real value of property `var`. How to escape the placeholder symbel `$`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this...

```
<properties>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <dollarSign>$</dollarSign>
    <maven.resources.escapeString>\</maven.resources.escapeString>
    <someVariable>${dollarSign}{junit.version}</someVariable>
</properties>
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${someVariable}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```